# request where there are at least 2 records in other table

Tags: sql, xml, join, xquery

I have this doc xml(short version) :

```
<Artiste>
        <artiste  a_id="A62" a_p_id="UK" a_date_nais="07/06/1952" a_sexe="M">
            <a_prenom>Liam</a_prenom>
            <a_nom>Neeson</a_nom>
        </artiste>
<artiste  a_id="A66" a_p_id="UK" a_date_nais="08/09/1971" a_sexe="M">
            <a_prenom>Martin</a_prenom>
            <a_nom>Freeman</a_nom>
        </artiste>
<Film>
        <film f_id="F1" f_p_id="FR" f_r_id="A61">
            <f_genre>P</f_genre>
            <f_titre>Banlieue 13</f_titre>
            <f_date_sortie>10/11/2004</f_date_sortie>
            <f_resume>fiction franÃ§aise</f_resume>
            <f_role ro_nom="LeÃ¯to" ro_a_id="A63"/>
            <f_role ro_nom="Lola" ro_a_id="A64"/> 
        </film>
        <film f_id="F2" f_p_id="NZ" f_r_id="A59">
            <f_genre>A</f_genre>
            <f_titre>Les seigneurs des anneaux</f_titre>
            <f_date_sortie>19/12/2005</f_date_sortie>
            <f_resume>fiction amÃ©ricaine</f_resume>
            <f_role ro_nom="PÃªcheur" ro_a_id="A25"/>
            <f_role ro_nom="SirÃ¨ne" ro_a_id="A2"/>
        </film>
</Film>
```

An artist play in a film(movie), an artist has a 'a_id" field in `Artiste` which is the same then in ro_a_id in `Film`

I want to select the name and first name (`a_prenom, a_nom`) of every artists that have played in at least 2 movies (`film`)

This is what I've done :

```
for $artiste in doc('S:/path/file.xml')//Artiste/artiste
  (: retrieve film $artiste is working in :)
  let $film := ('S:/path/file.xml')//Film/film[@ro_a_id=$artiste/@a_id]
  where count(@ro_a_id)>=2
  order by $artiste/@a_id
  return $x/a_nom, $x/a_prenom
```

So I don't know how to join and make the request, and I also don't know how to return 2 fields (I know that `$x/a_nom, $x/a_prenom` line generates an error)

Comment: FYI, your sample data is missing the close `</Artiste>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but your query has a couple of problems:

1. The `return` clause references an undefined variable `$x`. This should be changed to `$artiste`
2. Once that is fixed, you can return each actor's two name elements by constructing a sequence—by wrapping the items in parentheses: `($artiste/a_nom, $artiste/a_prenom)`. Alternatively you could return a single item, e.g., a string created by concatenating the two name parts, with `concat($artiste/a_nom, " ", $artiste/a_prenom)`.
3. Your `where` clause should reference the `$film` variable—specifically, `$film/f_role/@ro_a_id`.
4. Your sample data here doesn't contain any artists who appear in more than two of the films listed. So the `where` clause, even if fixed, will result in 0 hits.

I've posted a revised query to http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kp/1 showing these suggested changes. You'll see that I commented out the `where` clause so that we get some results.

Comment: Thank you for your explainations, it worked I had to slightly change the return statement and put an xml element tag but I guess it was because of baseX synthax.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make your query work is as follows:

```
for $artiste in doc('S:/path/file.xml')//Artiste/artiste
(: retrieve film $artiste is working in :)
let $film := doc('S:/path/file.xml')//Film/film[f_role/@ro_a_id=$artiste/@a_id]
where count($film)>=2
order by $artiste/@a_id
return ($artiste/a_nom, $artiste/a_prenom)
```

Here are the things I changed:

1. The expression `('S:/path/file.xml')` in line 3 should probably be `doc('S:/path/file.xml')`.
2. `@ro_a_id` is an attribute of `f_role`, not `film`.
3. You have to count the `film` elements, `@ro_a_id` is not in scope on line 4.
4. `$x` is never declared, you probably mean `$artiste`.
5. The final problem in the last row is that the *FLWOR* expression ends after the comma, so `$artiste/a_prenom` is not part of it. You can solve that by surrounding both parts with parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your explainations, your code also worked